# Transferring data on HDD to SDD with a Sata to USB Cable?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, gparted

I have an old T430 and I'm planning to swap out the HDD for an SSD. Unfortunately I have space for only one drive. Can I hookup the ssd with a Sata to USB cable and transfer my data on the HDD to the SSD with something like Gparted? Or would they both have to be installed and "in the computer" for this to work?

Comment: I have used two different USB to SATA adapters. I had an old 60GB SSD and used an adapter that used USB power. It worked for SSD, but would not spin up HDD as not enough power. I also converted a newer M.2 SSD to a USB to M.2 adapter. Both SSDs with USB3 ports were faster than expected. Multiple posts on users with adapters that would not work with larger drives or gpt drives or HDD (like my issue). If only for SSD then USB power ok, otherwise get one with external power and make sure it supports USB3 to larger drives. I found USB3 flash drives faster in USB2 ports on old system, so use USB3.

Answer (score 0):

The `gparted` can be used for the partitioning of the `SSD` but you would need another program like `rsync` to copy the files. Best done from a live USB install disk, you mount the old and new drives then a simple `rsync -avP /path/to/old/install/root_partition/* /path/to/new/install/root_partition/` should copy everything for you if just a one partition setup now. Once done switch the drive out and boot the live USB again to do a `boot-repair` so it will be bootable again once `GRUB` is installed on the new `SSD`.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: The problem is that I only have space for one drive, unless I can somehow mount it with the sata-usb cable.

Comment: Yes that is how it is done mount the `SSD` after you partition it. Then you do the copy of the drive, exchange the internal for the `SSD`. Do the boot-repair in the next boot and you should be able to boot your install from the `SSD` in the machine.

Comment: Ah, thank you! That's what I was wondering. Although I have seen a video of a guy using Gparted to "clone" his HDD onto another partition. Is this not the same as copying the files onto the SSD?

Comment: No clue have never used it, I know the method I described works.